# Just upgraded to Windows 8 - touchpad scrolling now extremely slow

Tags: windows, windows-8, mouse, touchpad, scrolling

Just like it sounds - I had Windows 7 and the touchpad scrolling was smooth and quick. Upgraded to Windows 8 and now it's very slow when I scroll through things. I set the scrolling speed to fastest in the device properties and also updated to the latest ultranav driver, but the issue persists.

This is a Thinkpad x220.

Comment: Maybe you already mentioned this but did is there a setting in "mouse" [or something similar] in control panel that lets you change the scroll speed? I know you can do this with mouse cursor speed, but I don't know if this is an option in Windows 8/8.1 and what it would exactly be called since I don't have a Windows 8 machine in front of me right now (building it!).

Answer (score 1):

Try to install synaptics generic touchpad controller: http://www.synaptics.com/resources/drivers Then you can customize your device settings. I don't have a Thinkpad x220 but it worked on my Packard Bell and on my Thinkpad R51.

Comment: this did not solve the issue :(

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late to answer, but in case somebody has the same problem in the future...

I've tried every driver I could find. From synaptics 14 to synaptics 17, and of course I tried all the ultranav provided by lenovo (I have a x220 too).

The only driver I found that provided the perfectly fast scrolling was 15.2.20.

The 15.2.20 has other issues, one irritating bug is that the palm sense is unpredictable. I wrote a small program that helps working around the bug, and maybe you will not have a problem with the bug. It's only a matter of how you position your hand on the keyboard.